# How to represent the behavior of an individual in an evolution simulation using binary valued genes?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, machine-learning, genetic-algorithm

Although I understand how to use binary valued genes(i.e. genes represented by binary strings) to represent characteristics like the color or speed of an individual in a genetic algorithm. I don't really understand how to represent an individual's behavior, such as its inclination to go after food, run away from predators, or **the general strategies an individual undertakes.**

Comment: Instead of binary valued genes use discrete-valued genes, or real-valued genes.

Comment: What are real-valued and discrete-valued genes?

Comment: See for example https://karczmarczuk.users.greyc.fr/TEACH/IAD/GenDoc/FlPointChromosome.pdf

Comment: I don't know if i correct understand, but it seems to my, you can tried something like professor Floreano. He perform neuroevolution and developed neural network control mobile robot. He also  perform coevolution, one neural net control predator and second prey. Predator and prey during process developed some strategies. [Interesting example](http://laral.istc.cnr.it/res/predprey/)